# Delete Entries in different DATABASE MysQL Query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

This works to delete rows in a different table, as long both tables are located on same database (thanks to Yadav Chetan for the query) :

```
    DELETE FROM BLOGS WHERE `id`  NOT IN
   (SELECT id FROM `USER`);
```

But what if the second table, USER, is located in a different database? (Named as "database2" here)

I was trying this, but no success:

```
DELETE FROM blogs
INNER JOIN database2.user
ON user.id=blogs.id 
WHERE `id` NOT IN
(SELECT id FROM `user`);
```

Comment: Why the INNER JOIN? Have you tried using alias? [..]FROM blogs b, INNER JOIN database1.user u, on u.id=b.id[...]

Comment: `DELETE b FROM database1.blogs AS b WHERE b.id  NOT IN (SELECT u.id FROM database2.user AS u);`

Comment: Basically, you only need the database names: `DELETE FROM database1.BLOGS WHERE id  NOT IN (SELECT id FROM database2.USER);`

Comment: yes that from   ypercube  actually worked